# Why does my progress bar rendering incorrectly?

Tags: java, android

[image: What is currently being rendered]

[image: Ideal render]

Hello,

I am trying to create a ring progress bar similar to the ideal image. I tried using the following xml code but for some reason it's coming out very wrong. I'm not sure why it is behaving this way so I would appreciate any help with figuring this out.

main xml file:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_marginTop="329dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_progress_bar_background"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

circular_progress_bar_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:thickness="20dp"
    android:useLevel="false"

    >
    <solid
        android:color="#bbb"
        />
</shape
```

> 

circular_progress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="150"
    android:toDegrees="150"
    >
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:thickness="20dp"
        android:useLevel="false"
        >
        <solid android:color = "#ef32d9"/>
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `useLevel="true"` tag to indicate progress percentage on your drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadius="24dp"
            android:thickness="6dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#bbb"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape android:shape="ring"
                android:innerRadius="24dp"
                android:thickness="6dp">
                <gradient
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:startColor="#FF5100"
                    android:endColor="#6C2200"
                    android:useLevel="true" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Note the `android:id` tags in the drawable declaration in order to tell our `ProgressBar` each drawable where it belongs.

Finally use it in your view:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:layout_marginTop="329dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Preview:

[image: Final result]